# Number of splits in rpart

Tags: r, split, decision-tree, rpart

In R, I'm going to create a decision tree using the rpart function. And I know that using the rpart.control parameter gives me a lot of control over the decision tree.
Then, How can I control the number of split nodes? Specifically, I want to control the number of branches that extend from one node. This is my code.

```
german<-read.csv("http://freakonometrics.free.fr/german_credit.csv", header=TRUE)

F=c(1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)
for(i in F) german[,i]=as.factor(german[,i])
str(german)

library(caret)
set.seed(1000)
intrain<-createDataPartition(y=german$Creditability, p=0.7, list=FALSE)  
train<-german[intrain, ]
test<-german[-intrain, ]

control_parameter<-rpart.control(maxdepth = 5)
rpartmod<-rpart(Creditability~. , data=train, control = control_parameter,method="class")
rpart.plot(rpartmod)
text(rpartmod)
```

-Additional comments

I want to make classification tree. So I transform the target variable to the factor type. And there are many factor variables. So when I perform pruning, the number of branches will be the number of levels per factor. So, when considering factor type variables, I want to control the number of split.

Comment: @MrFlick I want to make classification tree. So I transform the target variable to the factor type. And there are many factor variables. 
So when I perform pruning, the number of branches will be the number of levels per factor. So, when considering factor type variables, I want to control the number of split.

Comment: did get some solution to your question. If yes, please could you share, I too am looking for something similar.